# ActiveXObject runs in Javascript in asp.net page, but why not if the user's domain changes?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

My application runs well for most users, but fails without error for user from a different domain. It runs an ActiveXObject in a Javascript function within an Asp.net page.
I don't believe the code is faulty, it's something to do with the user being from a different domain but I don't know where to change a setting?

I don't know what to try as the program works for 99.9% of users; just not for the person from the otenhr domain who can see and operate the rest of the program, This bit just does not respond,

vb.net:

```
Dim nextpage As String
    nextpage = "frmStaffTrainingRecords.aspx?id=" & HRStaffId.Text
    InjectScript.Text = "<script>OpenTheFile('" & thedocument & "', '" & nextpage & "')</" + "script>"
```

asp.net:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

         function OpenTheFile(str,npag) {

           try { 
            var str2=str;
            fso = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell").Run(String.fromCharCode(34) + str2 + String.fromCharCode(34), 1, false);
           }
           catch (err) {
            }

          try{
          window.location.href = npag;
          }
          catch (err) {
             }

        }


    </script>
```

The code opens a selected file in it's related application - Word or Excel

Works for everybody except this one user.

Comment: Has the user got ActiveX enabled in their Internet Explorer settings? Are they definitely using Internet Explorer in the first place? Have you asked them to check for JavaScript errors in the console? If it's a single user affected, then look for differences in how they are accessing the page and what their setup is. You haven't told us about that and clearly we can't look at that ourselves, so all anyone can do is list a few possibilities, as I've done above.

Comment: Yes, I am testing on the same machine, logging on first as my usual account, logging out and back in again using the new account. So everything is the same except the user.